# How to make a field purchasable using payment module?

Tags: 7

I have a Drupal site where I want users to buy keys for getting access to member's complete profile. I fetched the data of the custom table of keys using views. I have keyname, key id as views fields. Now I have added another field (global text [buy now]).

Now I want to know how the key id of field can be made purchasable using payments module. How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to DA. What's your question?

Comment: @kenorb: IMHO "now I want to know how the key id can be made purchasable using payments module." sound like a question. True, it doesn't have a "?" at the end ... Wanna take "the risk" to edit the question to add that "?" ... and replace "now I want to know" by "My question:" ???

Comment: @sandeeptanwar What kind of payment module?